# ArrayList - get the highest int value?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

```
private static void theEnd() {
    Map<Client, Integer> Score = new HashMap<Client, Integer>();
    for (Client player : getPlayers()) {
        Client c = (Client) player;
        Score.add(c, c.gameScore);
    }
}
```

Basically, it loops through all clients, and adds their game score into my new Map Score.
Now, I have the arraylist ready with values, and I want to assign a winner in the game.

To be a winner, you must have the highest score.

**My question:**

*How can I find the highest game score in the map collection?*

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. You're missing the reference type of for loop variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only care to find the maximum score but not care which `Client` achieved it you can use  [`Collections.max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
 int maxScore = Collections.max(Score.values());
```

If you do care about the client and the score you can fetch the result with an anonymous [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) instance, which compares the map entries based on their value.

```
 Entry<Client, Integer> maxEntry = Collections.max(Score.entrySet(), 
       new Comparator<Entry<Client, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<Client, Integer> o1, Entry<Client, Integer> o2) {
                return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }
        }
  );
```

Also as a side note, the convention in Java is to give variables names that start with a lower case letter.

Comment: The thing is, I need to know what Client achieved it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a [Sorted Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)

Make sure to use the score as key, because the map is sorted by keys rather than values.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sorted collection like `TreeMap` which keeps its entries (key-value mappings) in natural order of their keys. Since, you want to sort on the high scores keep your scores as the keys and players as their values.

It's very likely that two or more players could have the same high scores. So, instead of mapping a score to a player we would have to map it to a `List` of players (with the same high score):

```
// {key - value} = {high score - {list, of, players}}
TreeMap<Integer, List<Client>> highestScores =
                               new TreeMap<Integer, List<Client>>();

for (Client client : getPlayers()) {
    List<Client> playerList = null;

    // make gameScore private
    Integer score = client.getGameScore(); // using getters() recommended

    // check if a player with this score already exists
    if ((playerList = highestScores.get(score)) == null) { // if NOT,
        playerList = new ArrayList<Client>(1); // CREATE a new list
        playerList.add(client);
        highestScores.put(score, playerList);
    } else { // if YES, ADD to the existing list
        playerList.add(client);
    }
}
```

To iterate over all the high scores use

```
for (Integer score : highestScores.descendingKeySet()) {
    for (Client player : highestScores.get(score)) { // iterate over player list
        System.out.println(player.getName() + ": " + score); // assuming "name" property
    }
}
```

To directly print out the highest score use

```
Map.Entry<Integer, List<Client>> highest = highestScores.lastEntry();
System.out.println(highest.getKey() + " : " + highest.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a Client called maxSoFar.
In the loop:
If maxSoFar == null, replace it.
else if c.gameScore() > maxSoFar.getScore() 
replace maxSoFar

When the loop is done, the client with the highest gamescore is in the maxSoFar variable.

Answer (score 0):

While you add elements to the map, you could save the maximum such as:

```
private static void theEnd() {
   int max = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;       
   Client winner = null;

   Map<Client, Integer> Score = new HashMap<Client, Integer>();
   for (Client player : getPlayers()) {
       Client c = (Client) player;
       Score.add(c, c.gameScore);

       if( c.gameScore > max ){
          max =c.gameScore;
          winner = c;
       }
   }
}
```

Then access the winner by variable `winner`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you use a `TreeSet` and override the compareTo method. Then you can also take the first or last entry based on your comparison. Basically I prefer that over the `TreeMap` as you don't need the additional key or value and work directly on the object (redundant data is omitted)

Answer (score 0):

If the `Client` class implements `Comparable<Client>` and has an implementation like this:

```
public int compareTo(Client that) {
     return Integer.compare(this.getScore(), that.getScore())
}
```

Then you could use

```
Client maxScoreClient = Collections.max(getPlayers());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are already running trough clients so just save the higest score key and then you have your client :)

```
 Map<Integer, Client> Score = new HashMap<Integer, Client>();
 Integer highestScore = 0;
    for (player : getPlayers()) {
        Client c = (Client) player;
        if(c.gameScore > highestScore ){
            highestScore = c.gameScore;
        }
        Score.add(c.gameScore, c);
    }

 Client winner = score.get(highestScore );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using different data-structure to solve your problem easily. Something like this :

```
Map<Integer, List<Client>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Client>>();

        for (Client player : getPlayers()) {

            int score = player.gameScore;

            if (map.containsKey(score)) {
                map.get(score).add(player);
            } else {
                List<Client> list = new ArrayList<Client>();
                list.add(player);
                map.put(score, list);
            }
        }
        Integer max = Collections.max(map.keySet());
        System.out.println(max); // Get the maximum score
        System.out.println(map.get(max)); // get the list of all the players with maximum score
```